# "Relation does not exist" error, only with libpq

Tags: c, postgresql, error-handling, libpq

I'm trying to run this query to insert new row to Users table from my C code using PQexec() (libpq)

```
INSERT INTO Users 
VALUES (( 
SELECT MIN(s.id) 
FROM generate_series(1,( 
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Id) + 1,1) FROM Users 
 )) AS s(id) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Id = s.id)) 
 , 'Tester', 27) 
RETURNING Id;
```

It performs what i need when i run it in psql terminal, but from C it returns

```
Error executing query: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

I checked connection status and it succeeded, using the same user i connect to from terminal. How come it can't find the users table?

EDIT: adding C-code
Connection:

```
sprintf(connect_param,"host=address dbname=%s user=%s password=%s",
                                                    USERNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
conn = PQconnectdb(connect_param);
```

Query:

```
sprintf(cmd, "INSERT INTO Users "
             "VALUES (( "
            "SELECT MIN(s.id) "
            "FROM generate_series(1,( "
            "SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Id) + 1,1) FROM Users "
            " )) AS s(id) "
            "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Id = s.id)) "
            " , \'%s\', %d) "
            "RETURNING Id;", Name, Age);
res = PQexec(conn,cmd);
```

Comment: can you post your actual C code rather than just the query

Comment: Are your connect parameters correct? You used `USERNAME` twice in the code you posted, once for `dbname=%s` and once for `user=%s`.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, they're the same.

Comment: The psql  terminal query isn't quite the same as the C query: `SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Id) + 1,1) FROM Users` versus `SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Users.Id) + 1,1)`.

Comment: Right, forgot to copy over the last change... still, result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going for deduction:

```
 Error executing query: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

This kind of error is throw when the databases doesn't find the table(view, or wathelse can pass through a SELECT, he gives the name of "relation") .So your code looks fine, but a sub-set of reasons can be:

- the table users doesn't exists. Some spelling mistake
- you perform the query in the wrong database (where this table is not defined)
- you perform the query in the wrong server (as above)
- you perform the query in the wrong schema (as above)
- The string get truncate from the sprintf.

and similar. The connection works very well since you get an answer from the database

Answer (score 0):

your problem of library link to compilation.

```
gcc -I/usr/include/postgresql/ -L/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/lib/ -lpq
```

Comment: don't think so... i'm compiling with the library, and i don't have any compilation or linking errors.